# Handling dynamic webtable using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

Iam trying to click a particular company and print the company name in the console from this website http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php# Iam getting no such element exception
This is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]/parent::td")).click();
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: It is showing no such element exception,there may be problem with xpath,Iam not ave to find exact xpath of that element

Comment: There is no "Marico Ltd" text on that page...

Comment: It is changing dynamically

Comment: But you trying to catch element by a specific text... So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Iam trying to find it using text and trying to click on it

Comment: But that text is not presented

Comment: It is showing ,it is dynamically changing when refreshed  ,so when trying to find xpath using row.,it is showing no such element exception

Comment: @Ammu posted an answer please see and let me know.

Comment: You can't find an element that isn't there. My answer solves the click problem but this page doesn't display the same companies every time it's loaded, including the company that your locator points to. You'll have to define what you want to happen when the company isn't on the page.

Comment: Actually I need to click that element and print that in the console.

Comment: @Ammu do you need to refresh the page until element is displayed and click on it?

Comment: Yes I need to do that

Comment: Please try my solution. Please let me know your response

Comment: Thanku all , problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to search for the element by refreshing the page until displayed.

**Note**: If the element is not displayed it will go into infinite loop so break it at some point.

**Method#1**: A loop to check for 10 times whether desired element is displaying or not.

```
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php#");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            if (isElementDisplayed()) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]/parent::td")).click();
                System.out.println("Navigated to Guru99 Bank at " + i + " iteration.");
                break;
            } else {
                driver.navigate().refresh();
                i++;
            }
        }
```

**Method#2**: Checks and returns the `boolean` value as `true` if element exists else returns `false`

```
public static boolean isElementDisplayed() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]/parent::td"));
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Navigated to Guru99 Bank at 4 iteration.
```

Comment: Don't hardcode the locator in `isElementDisplayed()`... instead take in a `By` and allow the locator to be passed in. This whole approach really isn't a good idea. Instead use `WebDriverWait` and it will basically do this for you without having to write all this code.

Comment: I read the whole question and all the comments. None of that changed my response.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch list of elements and check the size if it exists:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]"));
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", list.size() > 0);
```

Also you should not use `/parent::td` in `findElement`. Next you can click the element after the assertion

```
List.get(0).click()
```

Comment: Is my xpath correct,can someone help me out

Comment: I tested the code ... Its ok ... I change the xpath you wrote in my answer. You should not use `/parent::td` in `findElement`, which I remove it in my code

Comment: You never explained why `/parent::td` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is not necessarily wrong but in this case it's not working but we can fix it. The issue is that when Selenium attempts to click an element, it finds the x-y dimensions of the element and then clicks the exact center. In this case, the exact center of the TD misses the A tag (hyperlink).

The easiest way to fix this is to just click the A tag using the locator,

```
//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]
```

It's always a best practice to use `WebDriverWait` to ensure the element is ready before taking an action on it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Marico Ltd.')]"))).click();
```

Comment: The problem is that, Some times maybe there is no link contains 'MartinCo...' on the page and it's random. So your solution raise error after timeout ,I think

Comment: @HanaBzh Correct. I've asked OP to define what is to be done when the desired company is not on the page but have not received a response yet.